# element scrolls with page but should stop at specific top value

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a page which is very long. And I'm having a `<div id="scroll_tiles"></div>` which scrolls with the page but has a specific value at the beginning:

```
#scroll_tiles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 500px;
}
```

so what I'm doing is the following:

```
var scrollingDiv = jQuery("#sort_tiles");

jQuery(window).scroll(function(){           
    scrollingDiv
    .stop()
    .animate({"top": (jQuery(window).scrollTop()) + (50) + "px"}, "slow" );         
});
```

but when I'm scrolling back to the top, the div obviously does not stay at minimum `top: 500px` like in the beginning. How can make it, that the function works as it does, but when coming to `top: 500px` it keeps the div there, even if `scrolltop()` is less.

When I am scrolling down then again it should work like before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var scrollingDiv = jQuery("#sort_tiles");
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var myScrollTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + 50; // get the value
    myScrollTop = myScrollTop > 500 ? myScrollTop.toString() + "px" : "500px"; // validate if > 500

    scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"top": myScrollTop }, "slow");         
});
```

Comment: thank you it works, but what is basically happening there? I didn't know that I can do something like operators between an jquery function? Could you explain it, that I learn something.

Comment: I've edited my post to a better-view explanation. You can do whatever you want inside that function, even alert("Hello!"), if you want to.